# camera.release() not working

Tags: android, android-camera

i have develped a camera app which uses camera API from this [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html)

its working perfectly it shows preview takes picture but when i finish the app it never releases camera ...i can't use camera solely after installing this app ...even the app get crashed when i restart it.

here's how i am releasing the camera-->

```
      @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if (camera != null) {
         //   preview.setCamera(null);
            camera.stopPreview();
            camera.setPreviewCallback(null);
            camera.release();

            camera = null;
        }
    }
```

onResume i put this code also but didn't work..s

```
     @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        camera = Camera.open();

        preview.setCamera(camera);
    }
```

Comment: Have you implemented onDestroy as well?

Comment: Are you sure the problem is with the release() . Run the camera app, then close the app and try to launch native camera. If that launches, then i think your problem is in your onresume

Answer (score -1):

I have same problems on HTC One X (4.1.2) and Nexus 4(4.3), but on Galaxy Nexus (4.3) same release method works great.
I temporary solved this issue with using `camera.unlock()` instead of `camera.release()` and keeping static reference to Camera object.